# How to save a specific variable into session with "expire_on_close" = true in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know how to change laravel configuration in order to expire all session variables on close but I want to do this only for one variable and I want all other variables to remain in the browser on close!

I have searched a lot without any chance!

Comment: Short answer - you can't, unless you manually clear all other session variables on close.